# Why is findByViewId returning null?

Tags: android, android-activity

I feel like this is a brain damaged question, but for the life of me, I can't see what's wrong.

I have my activity that has the following definitions of buttons (in separate LinearLayout classes).

```
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/email_sign_in_button"
                style="?android:textAppearanceSmall"
                android:layout_width="250dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:text="@string/action_sign_in"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/forgot_password"
                style="?android:textAppearanceSmall"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_width="250dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginLeft="125dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:text="@string/action_forgot_password"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                />
```

Then I'm using this code:

```
    emailSignInButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.email_sign_in_button);
    emailSignInButton.setOnClickListener(loginClickListener);

    forgotPasswordButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.forgot_password);
    forgotPasswordButton.setOnClickListener(new ForgotPasswordListener());
```

And emailSignInButton works fine, while forgotPasswordButton is returning null. I've been sick or this would probably be obvious to me...

I tried dumping logcat and review for information, but didn't find anything probative.

Here's the entire xml file:

```
<!-- Login progress -->
<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/login_progress"
    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:visibility="gone"/>

<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/login_form"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/email_login_form"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView android:id="@+id/login"
                  android:layout_width="match_parent"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:gravity="center"
                  android:text="@string/login"
                  android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                  android:textSize="24sp"
            />

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <AutoCompleteTextView
                android:id="@+id/email"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="@string/prompt_email"
                android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:singleLine="true"/>

        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/password"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="@string/prompt_password"
                android:imeActionId="@+id/login"
                android:imeActionLabel="@string/action_sign_in_short"
                android:imeOptions="actionUnspecified"
                android:inputType="textPassword"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:singleLine="true"/>

        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>


        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/confirmPasswordLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:visibility="gone">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/confirmPassword"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="@string/prompt_confirm_password"
                android:imeActionId="@+id/login"
                android:imeActionLabel="@string/action_sign_in_short"
                android:imeOptions="actionUnspecified"
                android:inputType="textPassword"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:singleLine="true"
                />

        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            >
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/email_sign_in_button"
                style="?android:textAppearanceSmall"
                android:layout_width="250dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:text="@string/action_sign_in"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/create_account_button"
                style="?android:textAppearanceSmall"
                android:layout_width="250dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:text="@string/action_create_account"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            >
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/forgot_password"
                style="?android:textAppearanceSmall"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_width="250dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginLeft="125dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:text="@string/action_forgot_password"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                />
        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Entire onCreate() method:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
    // Set up the login form.
    emailView = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.email);
    populateAutoComplete();

    loginTitle = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.login);

    passwordView = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);
    passwordView.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onEditorAction(TextView textView, int id, KeyEvent keyEvent) {
            if (id == R.id.login || id == EditorInfo.IME_NULL) {
                attemptLogin();
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });

    confirmPasswordView = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.confirmPassword);

    confirmPasswordLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.confirmPasswordLayout);
    mainLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.mainLayout);

    LoginClickListener loginClickListener = new LoginClickListener();

    createAccountButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.create_account_button);
    createAccountButton.setOnClickListener(loginClickListener);

    emailSignInButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.email_sign_in_button);
    emailSignInButton.setOnClickListener(loginClickListener);

    forgotPasswordButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.forgot_password);
    forgotPasswordButton.setOnClickListener(new ForgotPasswordListener());

    loginFormView = findViewById(R.id.login_form);
    progressView = findViewById(R.id.login_progress);
}
```

I tried placing this button in the same LinearLayout as the other button to see if it made a difference. It didn't.

Comment: What do you mean with "in separate LinearLayout classes"? How did you load both LinearLayouts within your activity?

Comment: what yo mean by seperate linear layout?

Comment: please add the complete xml file, and the java activity code.

Comment: @AlexTa, that my activity contains multiple horizontal linear layouts inside of a vertical linear layout. This code is within the activity, so yes, they are all loaded.

Comment: show full java class

Comment: @MatiasElorriaga Added entire XML file. The code in the activity is too long for here. These lines of code are next to each other and in the activity.

Comment: please show only oncreate method

Comment: @Rodriquez done

Comment: Would you please send us the log cat too ? everything seems to be Ok right now @Thom

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it! I had at some point created multiple layouts for this activity for other device sizes. I no longer know why. So the code was running a different layout than the primary one.

I added my button to all of my layouts and it appears to have fixed the issue.

Feeling much better after a good night's sleep. Seems to have cleared my head.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is, that u initialize the method before you initialize Views.
So try with this:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
    // Set up the login form.
    emailView = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.email);
    confirmPasswordView = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.confirmPassword);
    confirmPasswordLayout = (LinearLayout)  findViewById(R.id.confirmPasswordLayout);
    mainLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.mainLayout);
    LoginClickListener loginClickListener = new LoginClickListener();
    createAccountButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.create_account_button);
    createAccountButton.setOnClickListener(loginClickListener);
    emailSignInButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.email_sign_in_button);
    emailSignInButton.setOnClickListener(loginClickListener);
    forgotPasswordButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.forgot_password);
    forgotPasswordButton.setOnClickListener(new ForgotPasswordListener());
    loginFormView = findViewById(R.id.login_form);
    progressView = findViewById(R.id.login_progress);
    loginTitle = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.login);
    passwordView = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);
    populateAutoComplete();
    passwordView.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onEditorAction(TextView textView, int id, KeyEvent keyEvent) {
            if (id == R.id.login || id == EditorInfo.IME_NULL) {
                attemptLogin();
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });

}
```

Also Iam suggest, you should use Butterknife[LINK](http://jakewharton.github.io/butterknife/)

This will clean your code

Comment: No, that wasn't it. I'm not sure what you think re-arranging the code will help. As I indicated, the button before was getting initialized properly.